# Is there a shortcut for setting labels in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, keyboard

How can I set a label on a folder with a keyboard shortcut from the finder?

Answer (score 6):

1. Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> when the folder is selected.

   This will bring up the **Get Info** box. Once you expand the section **General**, it will be already be expanded the next time you trigger the info box.
2. I've searched "MacOSX Hints" for tips and found [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110914115330820) which also refers to [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2011090810451459):

   With Lion you can add a toolbar icon to label a folder **with just one click**.

[image]

Comment: I think this is probably the best way of doing it. I just tried adding a shortcut (via System Preferences) but it seems the `Label:` menu entry is special one, so can't be bound to a key.

Comment: I can't seem to set the label using only my keyboard. I still have to move the mouse to the General section and set it there. It seems like this would be more of a hassle than right clicking and setting it that way.

Comment: @KitSunde Yeah, I wonder what a solution using *only* the keyboard would look like. After all, you still need to choose a color.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the answer but in Os X 10.9.

You now have Tags. Which use text and label colours to tag you finder items.

You can use the system keyboard shortcuts to activate on a file/s etc.

Go to  system preferences keyboard shortcuts.

- Select :The **Shortcuts** Tab.
- Select :**App Shortcuts**
- Click : the **+** button
- Set : the Application to : **Finder.app**
- Enter into:  the **Menu Title**: "Tags…"

The three dots …  at the end of **Tags…** are a special character called ellipsis.

Hold down the <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> key and type a press the semicolon key <kbd>;</kbd>  this will give you the correct three dots …

Make sure there is no space between Tags and the ellipsis

- Enter :  your **keyboard shortcut**.
- Click the **Add** button.

Thats it done.

Now when you have a finder item selected like a file. You can hit your shortcut and the Tags menu will be activate on the file.

You can then use the keyboard <kbd>⬆︎</kbd><kbd>⬇︎</kbd>  to navigate through your tags. And the <kbd>⏎</kbd>  key to first select and then the <kbd>⏎</kbd>  key again to complete

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've used [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/)  to assign shortcuts to AppleScripts like this.

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with f in items of (get selection)
            try
                set label index of f to item 1 of {2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7}
                -- 2 = red, 1 = orange, ..., 7 = gray, 0 = none
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: How do you apply this? Do you need to set a custom shortcut that launches the script?

Comment: @gentmatt With FastScripts you'd just save the scripts in ~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Finder/ with an app like AppleScript Editor and then assign shortcuts in its preferences. Another option would create Automator services with just a Run AppleScript action, set them to be available only in Finder, and then assign shortcuts in the Keyboard preference pane.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Automator to create a service, add "Label Finder Items" action with "files or folder" selected in the "Service receives selected" option.  Within that same option, make sure its in "Finder" only.
2. Save the service.
3. Go into System Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts and assign a shortcut.